# Open Dynamics Engine (ODE) support for custom bodies

Tags: opengl, 3d, render, game-engine

The Open Dynamics Engine (ODE) supports creation of rigid bodies like sphere, capsule, box etc. How can we create custom made bodies like a cloud, or a tree? I want to know if there is a way to get a partial sphere (may be a hemisphere) and then club it with a capsule so that it can behave as a custom made body?